# Override js class toString method

Tags: javascript

How can I explicitly define what will be return when I try to convert my instance to string? I tried this code.

```
class A {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.obj = obj
  }
  
  toString() {
    return this.obj.someValue
  }
}
```

But it does not work. When I called

```
const a = A({someValue: 12})
const str = `${a}`
```

`str` will be `{ obj: { someValue: 12} }`.

Comment: A should be called with `new`.

Comment: every thing else is perfect

Comment: After your edit to add `new`, the code works.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue you describe with the updated snippet - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12mnuyfe/1/)

Comment: Why did you remove the `new` after you just added it in the previous edit?

Comment: @Andreas because I missed it on my code too and that was a reason why my code does not work correct. I guess it's better to add an answer with correct code

Comment: The `new` (missing or not) does not explain the stated output. Either your script works as expected or it throws an error because of the missing `new` and wouldn't output anything. Either way this is not a [mcve]

Comment: @Andreas it was my bad. I missed a line with converting instance to string on my machine too. All problem was with missing `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A should be called with `new`  keyword

```js
class A {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
  }

  toString() {
    return this.obj.someValue;
  }
}

// A should be called with new 
const a = new A({ someValue: 12 });
const str = `${a}`;

console.log(str);
```